# Blocking Spam from Sendgrid

Tags: email, block, sendgrid, spam

Since July 3, we have been receiving hundreds of spam emails from Sendgrid, through Rackspace to our emails.

I have blacklisted the full SendGrid IP range 192.254.125.xxx

I have blacklisted the sender email - bounce@smecos.bes

I have blacklisted the sender domain - smecos.best

I have verified that there is no entry on our whitelist for it.

Does anyone have an idea on how to block this?

```
Delivered-To:   myemail@mydomain.com
Return-Path:    <bounces+14130655-c4d2-myemail=mydomain.com@sendgrid.net>
Delivered-To:   myemail@mydomain.com
Received:   from director12.mail.ord1d.rsapps.net ([172.27.255.8]) by backend25.mail.ord1d.rsapps.net with LMTP id OALhG8KxBF9jTAAAANS3aA for <myemail@mydomain.com>; Tue, 07 Jul 2020 13:32:50 -0400
Received:   from proxy10.mail.iad3a.rsapps.net ([172.27.255.8]) by director12.mail.ord1d.rsapps.net with LMTP id WBInGcKxBF/cKgAAIasKDg ; Tue, 07 Jul 2020 13:32:50 -0400
Received:   from smtp15.gate.iad3a ([172.27.255.8]) (using TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)) by proxy10.mail.iad3a.rsapps.net with LMTP id QPz7EsKxBF80MAAAnQ/bqA ; Tue, 07 Jul 2020 13:32:50 -0400
Return-Path:    <bounces+14130655-c4d2-myemail=mydomain.com@sendgrid.net>
X-Spam-Exception:   WHITELISTED
X-Spam-Threshold:   95
X-Spam-Score:   100
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL:     9
Precedence:     junk
X-Spam-Flag:    YES
X-Virus-Scanned:    OK
X-Orig-To:  myemail@mydomain.com
X-Originating-Ip:   [192.254.125.54]
Authentication-Results:     smtp15.gate.iad3a.rsapps.net; iprev=pass policy.iprev="192.254.125.54"; spf=pass smtp.mailfrom="bounces+14130655-c4d2-myemail=mydomain.com@sendgrid.net" smtp.helo="o19225412554.outbound-mail.sendgrid.net"; dkim=pass header.d=sendgrid.net; dmarc=none (p=nil; dis=none) header.from=smecos.best
X-Suspicious-Flag:  NO
X-Classification-ID:    e0a3814e-c077-11ea-8ea3-525400f46865-1-1
Received:   from [192.254.125.54] ([192.254.125.54:40911] helo=o19225412554.outbound-mail.sendgrid.net) by smtp15.gate.iad3a.rsapps.net (envelope-from <bounces+14130655-c4d2-myemail=mydomain.com@sendgrid.net>) (ecelerity 4.2.38.62370 r(:)) with ESMTPS (cipher=AES256-GCM-SHA384) id 69/3D-03017-1C1B40F5; Tue, 07 Jul 2020 13:32:49 -0400
DKIM-Signature:     v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=sendgrid.net; h=content-type:from:subject:to; s=smtpapi; bh=kfSTUxrtrj7Cfftqpn3LN0WgHvE5kCnC+uOSG98vgVw=; b=h9mc6mDQC6rOc ccC9wL3Kli8FNwOSt5jau76QDpLrBAbHKhT396C0WbX2/KSD3uThrlp4nUXnvjSz r89bSPYTB6MJrgneNAlDS8NUaLi+NsKiUoR2rzuNp4DiS7srNyXLmpiDD2CT1ngR 1sWo8vVID+7G9+Zj/LmG4Hf8n1JV44=
Received:   by filter1449p1las1.sendgrid.net with SMTP id filter1449p1las1-6945-5F04B1AF-2 2020-07-07 17:32:31.196480369 +0000 UTC m=+669233.137313263
Received:   from localhost.local (unknown) by ismtpd0002p1lon1.sendgrid.net (SG) with ESMTP id ubRiQA93Qiu1jVJoiOUwWA for <myemail@mydomain.com>; Tue, 07 Jul 2020 17:32:30.923 +0000 (UTC)
Content-Type:   text/html;
From:   LeafFilter Promotion <bounce@smecos.best>
Subject:    Clean-Flowing Gutters For Life. NOW 10% Off
To:     myemail@mydomain.com
Date:   Tue, 07 Jul 2020 17:32:31 +0000 (UTC)
Message-ID:     <ubRiQA93Qiu1jVJoiOUwWA@ismtpd0002p1lon1.sendgrid.net>
X-SG-EID:   pcWxy9UBUtUw1gLvETZLKtJE+upTXkXQzSeXVboYOfj8445+b2JsYfGgCpUWh8jVevl8/mhHKM7/bO cH66Ixkc6hUTlPM1+gw7fPZ+GgUnTm9aSlAe3BVn04Ij2UoKzBcvDZTSeQ36bqJOD3LuCa3N042M5N 5w7kLpwCQtqtjsCrM4HXT078AKROMUSpgkSXwz0ZXJbX5V+mjjJlMheILWef2HZCdQIqmghlz64LFz s=
```

Answer (score 1):

Postfix Filter header_checks.pcre on

`/^Message-ID: .*\.sendgrid\.net\>$/     REJECT spam emails from Sendgrid`

Comment: We use rackspace for email and as far as I know we can't block header items, only IP, or sender.  In the case of sendgrid, they have a range of ips, and the sender of the spam is always changing  I guess I'll just block all of sendgrid ips.  They used to be a good company but got sold.